# Can I get S.M.A.R.T. support on external hard drives?

Tags: hardware, usb, external-disk, firewire, monitoring

Disk Utility reports the [S.M.A.R.T. Status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) as not verified for external disks, and by default Mac OS X only seems able to access S.M.A.R.T. information on internal hard drives.

Is there a way to get SMART information on external USB or Firewire hard disk?

Comment: Interestingly enough, Windows tools like CrystalDiskInfo can access SMART data over USB when running under VMWare Fusion. So technically you can access SMART on Mac OS X if you have VMWare with Windows. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes (maybe).

There's an open-source kernel driver [OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver](https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver) for Mac OS X that will work for some USB and Firewire enclosures. It uses [SAT (SCSI ATA Translation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_/_ATA_Translation) to pass the SMART commands through to the hard drive, so **only works if your enclosure supports SAT**.

SAT isn't something enclosures seem to advertise support for, but the one I use (WD MyBook Studio Edition) happens to support it, so it works for me. It'll probably be quicker to test the software with your drive/enclosure, than to find out if SAT is supported in the specs.

Comment: Although this may not be the only option to get the SMART status, as I could not retrieve the SMART status for a drive in an enclosure using a Sunplus Technology USB to SATA bridge in OS X - but from the same combination of HDD and enclosure I could successfully get the SMART data using Windows XP (even in a virtual machine) and [HDDScan](http://hddscan.com/) (see Appendix A on that site for supported controller chips)

Comment: The Sharkoon SATA Quickdeck Pro doesn't seem to support SAT. Tested with OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver version 0.6. Three different external hard disk enclosures (Toshiba DWC130 HDWC130EK3J1, Hitachi Touro DX3 DTOLDX1EB40001ABB, Gdrive GDRU3EA5001ADB) did support SAT.

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices for a list of supported devices.

Comment: @ProBackup The page you linked lists many different kinds of devices that are supported by smartmontools; is it just the ones that indicate options `-d sat` that are supported by the SAT SMART Driver?

Comment: @rakslice When I re-read the "Supported devices" table, I would say **yes** only the USB drives with `-d sat` are supported via the SAT SMART driver.

Answer (score -1):

There are satsmart drivers on github that work perfectly well for most (usb) disks.
Disconnect all external disks;
Install the satsmart driver;
restart the mac, connect the disks.
See and download from here: https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx/usb-drive-support

Comment: Why do you add a link to a site offering a product for money if the drivers are available on Github?

Comment: @nohillside Because apparently the Github developer is no longer maintaining the driver: https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver/issues/63#issuecomment-695833929