# How do I get detailed SMART disk information on OS X (Mavericks or later)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, diskutil

I'm trying to get a detailed SMART status report on the drives in my Mac. I'm not talking about "Verified," I'm talking about the detailed report that's about 100 lines long listing all the vital statistics of the drive.

Anyone know how to do this with diskutil? If diskutil can't do it is there a different free tool I can use?

Comment: For external USB devices on Big Sur, you're out of luck: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/52604/79496 ... https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver/issues/62#issuecomment-703483600 ... https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx/kb#external-drive-support-macos-11. Essentially, there is no SMART support for external USB devices in macOS, and the two programs which are supposed to resolve this (`OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver` and `DriveDx`) are both currently broken in this regard. The former is no longer in active development, and with `DriveDx` you have to unplug / replug your device for it to work.

Comment: @GDP2 With Monterey the need to unplug / replug devices is no longer needed. So `DriveDX` is no longer partially broken.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I recently had the same question and found a command line tool [www.smartmontools.org](http://www.smartmontools.org) which can be installed via brew:

```
brew install smartmontools
```

Also via MacPorts:

```
sudo port install smartmontools
```

you can then run it

```
smartctl -a disk0s3
```

for the full report where `disk0s3` is the disks physical backing which can be found in Disk Utility.app by getting info on the drive. (or via `diskutil list` on command line.) Here is an example of the output:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 840 Series
Serial Number:    S14LNEAD609248A
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 5503acd2e
Firmware Version: DXT08B0Q
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jun 19 16:34:10 2014 MDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (53956) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  70) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2379
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1579
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   096   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       38
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   059   039   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1571
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       14090964124

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  255        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Perfect! I had to use -a instead of -H to get a full report. Not sure if this is because you had a different version of smartctl or a typo.

    smartctl -a disk0

Comment: Yes, it was suppose to be -a, I have corrected my answer

Comment: I get in the latest OSX this error: /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0 Do you know why?

Comment: @Masi Have you upgraded to Yosemite since you last used brew? I remember having some errors after the upgrade and search for a fix specific to my problem.

Comment: @LeeJoramo You are right. Correct solution here to my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/24244945/54964

Comment: And if you want to get SMART status from USB devices, you need to install this kernel extension: https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver (source) - https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx/usb-drive-support (signed binary)

Comment: "There must be a way to find this under OS X at the command line." I think you mean using the build in command 'diskutil list' here :)

Comment: I'm trying to get TBW from the drive (`-l devstat /dev/disk1`) but I get this error: `ATA_READ_LOG_EXT (addr=0x00:0x00, page=0, n=1) failed: 48-bit ATA commands not implemented. ... Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported`

Answer (score 19):

Here's two extra nuggets of knowledge that may be of assistance:

1. the `smartmontools` package is also available under MacPorts. If you have MacPorts installed, `sudo port install smartmontools` will do the trick
2. the `df` command will quickly give you an idea of what is mounted where.

Comment: After installing smartmontools with ports I don't have access to `smartctl` ...says "command not found"... even after running `sudo port load smartmontools` and restarting the machine... any ideas?

Comment: @Labrador Do you have /opt/local/bin in your PATH?

Answer (score 18):

Extending on [Lee Joramo's excellent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135566/45492) you can install the [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/index.php) GUI on top of `smartmontools`. It comes in a Homebrew tap.

So the procedure is:

```
brew install smartmontools
brew install gsmartcontrol

gsmartcontrol
```

Or, if you use MacPorts:

```
sudo port install gsmartcontrol
```

(which will automatically install `smartmontools` as a dependency)

BTW: I had to activate SMART first. The GUI can do that for you. If you want to use the command line it is `smartctl -s on -a disk0s2`.

Comment: Something appears to be missing here... I installed `gsmartcontrol` (with tons of dependencies) using macports, but running `gsmartcontrol` gets a Gtk warning that it cannot open the display. What else is required?

Answer (score 5):

Quite new and compatible with MacOS Sierra, Yosemite and El Capitan option:

Get native precompiled package from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/

Install it, open Terminal and run:

```
 sudo /usr/local/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/disk0
```

You will get full output like this:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [Darwin 16.3.0 x86_64] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron MX100/MX200/M5x0/M600 Client SSDs
Device Model:     Crucial_CT500MX200SSD1
Serial Number:    16151248FBA4
...
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
...
```

and following rest of SMART information.
Hope this helps to users who want simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information running smartctl 7.1 on macOS 10.15 (Catalina)+

Behaviour / output varies if SSD types are different, e.g. NVMe vs SATA/SATA Express

## NVMe

MacBookPro14,3 (NVMe) 512GB `SM0512L`, `smartctl` actually can retrieve a field named `Data Units Written` which is equivalent to `Total LBAs Written`.

```
  Link Width:   x4
  Link Speed:   8.0 GT/s

# smartctl output

smartctl -a /dev/disk0
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [Darwin 19.5.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       APPLE SSD SM0512L
Serial Number:                      C0281xxxxxxxx2
Firmware Version:                   CXS5EA0Q
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Controller ID:                      2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Local Time is:                      Thu Jul  2 12:05:31 2020 AEST
Firmware Updates (0x06):            3 Slots
Optional Admin Commands (0x0006):   Format Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x001f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         256 Pages

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        5       5
 1 -   0.0400W       -        -    1  1  1  1      210    1200
 2 -   0.0050W       -        -    2  2  2  2     1900    5300

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        35 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    45,208,642 [23.1 TB]
Data Units Written:                 44,739,539 [22.9 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 1,440,047,433
Host Write Commands:                833,678,921
Controller Busy Time:               1,952
Power Cycles:                       7,356
Power On Hours:                     1,190
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   47
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0

Read Error Information Log failed: NVMe admin command:0x02/page:0x01 is not supported
```

## SATA / SATA Express via AHCI

(Mid 2015) MacBookPro11,5 (under SATA/SATA Express but still PCIe based SSD) 512GB `SM0512G`

- physical interconnect - PCI
- AHCI 1.30 though

`175 Host_Writes_MiB` is the key.

```bsh
terrywang@ninja:~$  smartctl -a /dev/disk0
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [Darwin 19.5.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Apple SD/SM/TS...E/F/G SSDs
Device Model:     APPLE SSD SM0512G
Serial Number:    S------------63
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 900000000
Firmware Version: BXW1SA0Q
User Capacity:    500,277,790,720 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jul  2 12:17:35 2020 AEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       5303
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -       32789
169 Unknown_Apple_Attrib    0x0013   239   239   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       3629423527808
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   196   196   100    Old_age   Always       -       21484011576
174 Host_Reads_MiB          0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       26175030
175 Host_Writes_MiB         0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       19170887
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   073   018   000    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 9/82)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Warning! SMART Selective Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  255        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

## Samsung SSDs - How Magician software calculates health status

Samsung Magician simply use a SSD's TBW as health indicator, for example, 850 EVO 250GB (designed TBW 75GB)

2.56TB / 75TB = 3.41%  of its designed capacity.

> NOTE: On Linux (or Windows), S.M.A.R.T. - ID 241 `Total LBAs Written` is the one to look at, but please be aware it reports the number of 512-byte sectors, you'll need to do math to convert to TB or TiB.

Formula: (Total_LBAs_Written * sector size) / 1024^4 = TiB
Convert TiB to TB (facepalm) / TBW -> % designed lifespan

Answer (score 1):

You can get quite a lot of information from the free version of SmartReporter: https://www.corecode.io/smartreporter_lite/

Drop into Utilities and double click it. Click on icon in bar at top of screen. Right click on a disk in preferences and play with options.

Answer (score 1):

Most MacOS don't support SMART and if your trying to do a MacART attribute applied it will fail installs and it causes the system to freeze up after each action performed, like copying a file, at the end of the process it locks up the OS. This is due to SMART reading the data in/out on the drive at the moment it drops the file the SMART sensors cause the system to freeze from not being supported on a monitored system, it's not supported. If you have SMART enabled on a Mac or a Mac OS, go into disk utility and at the bottom in the disk info you will see it says, SMART not supported. Most of the MacOS I know of don't support this feature and to get a hackintosh to install most of the distro installers without your system being rejected, you must not enable this feature. I have even had Linux mint in virtualbox installed in aRAM drive say that it didn't support SMART. I will post a few pics. Every hard drive that has this feature doesn't work with MacOS very well.
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score -3):

[Here is a complete guide to smartmontools on osx](https://bitbucket.org/benjamin-von-der-weiden/smartmontools-mac-osx-howto/src/56c1b851eacf82e779474c55db8bd780a94c6143/smartmontools-mac-osx-howto.txt?fileviewer=file-view-default), including where to find it, how to install it, and how to use it, by the author Benjamin von der Weiden.