# What tools read SMART data and can run on USB bootable media?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a bootable tool that provide SMART values from my HDD if there is such a thing.

So far I'm only able to get into the recovery mode of my MacBook Pro and I need to confirm a malfunctioning HDD.

As far as I know I can't install any software in Recovery Mode? I have SMART utility but I can't think of any way on how to use it like this.

Any good recommendations for a USB or CD bootable solution to check my HDD SMART values?

Comment: OS X boots on any media and you can thin an install greatly if you use a tool to delocalize and look at folder sizes. Are you open to any tool that reads SMART data so you can cook up your own OS X minimal installation if you can't live with the ~8 GB needed for a full OS install? Sadly, my recent Mac's don't show SMART data in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 2):

The process to make your own test rig is quite easy:

1. Install OS X onto a USB hard drive. A partition with 20 GB should be just fine.
2. Use the Startup Disk preference pane to reboot to that new OS and create an admin user.
3. Install homebrew - https://brew.sh
4. Install smartmontools - `brew install smartmontools`
5. Get a USB drive or SD card if you don't want to boot from the hard drive/partition.
6. Thin out files if your image won't fit on the chosen media (or buy larger media)
7. Use Disk Utility to **Restore** the OS from the partition to the media chosen

Now you have a UDB/SD card that can boot your Mac and [run one of the best free SMART tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135565/how-do-i-get-detailed-smart-disk-information-on-os-x-mavericks-or-later).